# Getting ID of product then getting subcategory and product titles from another table

Tags: php, mysql, join

Here i am stuck with a query

I have this table  PRODUCT  where i have products listed with product id , title ,subcategory id and category id  . There is another table (procat) where i have procat id and parent id , procat title  . so basically an id which has parent id is a subcategory if 0 then its a category thats my logic

Now basically what i want to do is fetch   product title , category title and subcategory title i can get the category though but how can i get subcategory as well

```
SELECT
product.id,
product.title AS product_title,
procat.title  AS category_title  
FROM product,
procat 
WHERE product.procatid = procat.id
OR  product.procatsubid = procat.id
AND product.procatid = '31'
AND product.procatsubid = '21'
```

I have also tried left join but to no avail

Answer (score 0):

**Edit** - Thanks for clarifying. It seems that there might be redundancy in the Product foreign keys to category (i.e. product should possibly just be classified by a procat SubCategory, and the parent category id be arrived at by navigating procat.parent (possibly recursively)

```
SELECT
  product.id,
  product.title AS product_title,
  cat.title  AS category_title,
  subcat.title AS subcategory_title  
FROM product 
   INNER JOIN procat cat on product.procatid = cat.id
   INNER JOIN procat subcat on product.procatsubid = subcat.id
  procat
WHERE product.procatid = '31'
      AND product.procatsubid = '21'
      -- The below should be redundant, but I guess you can use them to ensure that the product FKs are correct and the table integrity is maintained
      AND cat.parentid = 0
      AND subcat.parentid <> 0
```

Comment: getting multiple values with this one .... I need to get is product title , i have the category id so cataegory title  and i have the subcategory id  so title of subcategory actually in procat the category and subcategories are listed same way only difference between them is parent id if a procat id has parent id it means its a subcategory otherwise 0